# Is it possible to know before execution if the variable would be changed with ast Python?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a string with python code inside, for example:

```
df.head()
```

and

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Is it possible, using ast to know  whether the execution will change initial variable(second case) or not(first case)

Comment: Not from AST alone. This would need a complicated measures like code analysis or a simulated execution which could be rolled back.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible in the general case as outlined in the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). This goes for all languages, not just python.